# My client wants to pass a self signed certificate with every axios call. how can i achieve this?

Tags: reactjs, axios

My React App is making a POST call to a webhook.My client wants to pass a self signed certificate with every axios call made from the browser.

I have the keys but i am not able to set it in the headers.

Comment: You can't add it to the headers of the request? Like this: `axios.post(apiPath, params, { headers: { 'foo': 'bar' } }, });`

Comment: I already have the certificate file. Can you give me the syntax how can i pass it in my axios post call?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axioscreateconfig):

`var instance = axios.create({
   ...
   headers: {'Self-Signed-Header': 'certificate'}
});`

Use it like so:

`instance.get('/route/needing/that/cert')`

Note: It may help (if this answer is irrelevant) to clarify where you would be "passing" this data in a normal request; I assume it is a header based on you saying you weren't able to set it in a header, but that was inferred